# Regex Help- Escaping Characters And Matcher Method

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I have a string:

```
allPunctuation = '~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-\'\\';
```

This string contains APEX's way of escaping characters so I can include the `'` and the `\` characters.

When I pass this string into the `replaceAll()` method I get back an error because the escape characters are not carried over and the regex needs the escape characters. Is there a way around this?

ie: when I `system.debug` `allPunctuation` I get back: ~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-'\ This clearly doesn't have the escape characters anymore.

My second thought was to utilize the matcher method. Documentation found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm

I am not sure why, but it is returning back a `false`. To me it seems like it shouldn't be affected by the escape quotes. And legalName has all sorts of punctuation in it.

```
Pattern NonAlphanumeric = Pattern.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]');
Matcher matcher = NonAlphanumeric.matcher(legalName);
//system.debug(matcher) ---> false
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your commented out debug couldn't be right...the `matcher` variable is a `Matcher` instance, not a `Boolean`.

Comment: Sometime you have to use find to get matches to be true. Not well versed on why but have had to do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can match all punctuation using `\\p{Punct}`, as mentioned in the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, which matches:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

For example, the following code results in an empty String:

```
String s = '~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-\'\\';
System.debug(s.replaceAll('\\p{Punct}',''));
```

Note that the "escapes" are not disappearing, they're being compiled. If you want a literal backslash escape, you have to escape it *twice*:

```
String s = '~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-\\\'\\\\';
```

Where `\\\'` results in the pattern/matcher/regexp engine seeing `\'`, and `\\\\` results in the engine seeing `\\`.

Adrian's solution also works, but I think that `\p{Punct}` is a bit more explicit with declaring the *intent* of your code (to match any punctuation).

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is to use the `\W` character as your entire expression, it matches any non-word character. Unfortunately, this solution would also match any whitespace characters, and ignore the underscore character (`_`).

Here's the expression I would use:

```
(_|[^\w\s])
```

What does it mean?

- 1st Capturing Group `(_|[^\w\s])`
  Matches either alternative

  - 1st Alternative `_`

    - `_` matches the character `_` literally (case sensitive)
  - 2nd Alternative `[^\w\s]`

    - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\w\s]`
    - `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Here are some examples:

```
String expression = '(_|[^\\w\\s])';

String allPunctuation = '~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-\'\\';
String input1 = 'This is a test!', output1 = 'This is a test';
String input2 = 'This is a test...', output2 = 'This is a test';
String input3 = '([{This_is_a_test}])', output3 = 'Thisisatest';

system.assertEquals('', allPunctuation.replaceAll(expression, ''));
system.assertEquals(output1, input1.replaceAll(expression, ''));
system.assertEquals(output2, input2.replaceAll(expression, ''));
system.assertEquals(output3, input3.replaceAll(expression, ''));
```

Given example 3, you may want to change things up and replace underscores with space characters instead. Then you could simplify somewhat:

```
String sanitize(String name)
{
    if (name == null) return name;
    return name.replaceAll('[^\\w\\s]', '')
        .replaceAll('_', ' ').trim();
}

String allPunctuation = '~!@#$%^*()_+|}{":?><`=;/.,][-\'\\';
String input1 = 'This is a test!     ', output1 = 'This is a test';
String input2 = 'This is a test...   ', output2 = 'This is a test';
String input3 = '([{This_is_a_test}])', output3 = 'This is a test';

system.assertEquals('', sanitize(allPunctuation));
system.assertEquals(output1, sanitize(input1));
system.assertEquals(output2, sanitize(input2));
system.assertEquals(output3, sanitize(input3));
```