# Regex - Replace regex character with escape character in front of it

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

I am able to replace regex character to blank with the following code:

`str = str.replaceAll('\\p{Punct}', '');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, '***str: ' + str);`

Here is the reference that I got the above code:
[Regex Help- Escaping Characters And Matcher Method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196769/regex-help-escaping-characters-and-matcher-method)

But how to add the escape character and not replace it to blank?

for example:

```
"This is the string [the-string] that will be replaced with escape character in regex"
```

what I want:

```
"This is the string \[the\-string\] that will be replaced with escape character in regex"
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

I tried using

```
String str = 'This is the string [the-string] that will be replaced with escape character in regex';
str = str.replaceAll('\\p{Punct}', '\\$&');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, '***str: ' + str);
```

But the output is:

```
***str: This is the string $&the$&string$& that will be replaced with escape character in regex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $0 to include the matched expression in the replacement. As mentioned in the prior answer, you need to double-escape the escape character to get a literal escape character to the regexp engine, and you need to escape the escape character to get a literal escape character in the resulting string, for a total of four escape characters (`\\\\`). The resulting code looks like this:

```
String str = 'This is the string [the-string] that will be replaced with escape character in regex';
str = str.replaceAll('\\p{Punct}', '\\\\$0');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, '***str: ' + str);
```

Output:

> [3]|DEBUG|***str: This is the string \[the\-string\] that will be replaced with escape character in regex